# How to make foil effect image?

Tags: photoshop-effects, effects

How can I make a card image with foil effect?

Which tool and effect options should I use?

Original

[image]

Foil effect

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: It appears to merely be a multi-color gradient overlay at a low opacity. Any number of applications are capable of that. (Not certain I'd call this "foil")

Comment: @Scott Its the correct answer, I'd upvote if you made it one. The procedure to achieve this effect.on the physical cards is called 'holofoiling'; cards treated as such are colloquially known as 'foil'.

Comment: Hi John, welcome to GDSE. I downvoted your question because your description is very limited and you didn't show what you have tried already. If you could edit your question to include a description, its quality would improve. Thanks!

Comment: @Vincent Got it I will try myself first and try improve question Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't really bring much to anything new to what's already been said, but I think cards like this are often called "hologram cards", "holographic cards" or "holo cards".

Answer (score 2):

This merely appears to be a multi-colored gradient placed above the artwork, then the opacity of the gradient is lowered until you get the desired appearance.

There are *many* software applications which can do this - from free or online software to professional software. Which you choose is up to you. Without designating a particular applications, it's a bit too broad to give any direct step-by-step assistance.